# Check authenticity of user Using aadhar card number

Tags: java, php, android

In my android application I want to check aadhar card number entered by the user belongs to that particular user by sending an OTP to the user on his registered mobile number with that aadhar card.

> **Aadhaar** is a 12 digit individual identification number issued by the Unique Identification Authority of India on behalf of the Government of India.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the API documentation here: https://uidai.gov.in/images/resource/aadhaar_otp_request_api_1_6.pdf

Once you accept the OTP from the user, you can authenticate the user using the API documented here: https://uidai.gov.in/images/FrontPageUpdates/aadhaar_authentication_api_1_6.pdf

Comment: I have gone through it. It gives me access only after I am registered a an AUA. Isn't there is other way.?

Comment: There is a Google group community that can assist you on all your queries. Please check https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/aadhaarauth

Comment: I have gone through it too. Its also told be to be an AUA but the financial requirement (turnover of the company) for it is too high.